# How do I take pdf to Full screen in angular?

Tags: angular, npm

I just coded a pdf viewer using `ng2-pdf-viewer`
and now I want pdf to go full screen the way it goes in presentations or other pdf viewers
I've no clue about how to do it, any help will be appreciated

this is my code so far:

```
 <button (click)="prev()">Previous</button>
  <button (click)="next()">Next</button>
  
  <pdf-viewer [src]="src" 
      [show-all]="false"  
      [page]="page"

      [fit-to-page]="true" >
      
      
  </pdf-viewer>
```

this is component.ts file

```
title = 'pdfer';
  // src = "https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf";
  src = "../assets/DBMS.pdf"
  page=1;

  pageRendered(e: CustomEvent) {
    console.log('(page-rendered)', e);
  }
  next(){
    this.page+=1;
  }
  prev(){
    this.page-=1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The property **[fit-to-page]** show your document in orignal size

There is another property known as **[original-size]**

If `original-size=true` then the size will be same as the original document

if `original-size=false` then the size will be same as the container block

So, to solve the problem you can set orignal-size property to false. For more information about available properties check [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer#original-size)

**EDIT: ngx-extended-pdf-viewer**

1. Install **ngx-extended-pdf-viewer**

   - `npm i ngx-extended-pdf-viewer --save`
2. In **angular.json** file import assets under assets array

   ```
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      {
       "glob": "**/*",
       "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/locale",
       "output": "/assets/locale/"
      },
      {
       "glob": "**/*",
       "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/images",
       "output": "/assets/images/"
      },
      {
       "glob": "**/*",
       "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
       "output": "/assets/"
      }
    ],
   ```
3. In **.module.ts** file import NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule

   ```
    import { NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';
    imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule
    ],
   ```
4. In **.component.html** file

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="docURL" [useBrowserLocale]="true" [textLayer]="true" [showHandToolButton]="true">
</ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

5. For all available options check [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer)
6. [Github Project Link](https://github.com/faiziiii05/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer-example)
7. Sample Output [image: Sample Output]

Comment: thanks for the reply, I believe that the methods you mentioned make it to full WINDOW, and what I need if full SCREEN

Comment: @SadafShafi What do you mean by Full Screen? Not this behavior you are expecting  https://ng2-pdf-viewer-e8umxx.stackblitz.io/

Comment: not really the ono you showed, its a full window. Try pressing F11 or Fn+F11 while you're on your browser, and You'll get a full screen

Comment: @SadafShafi oh I got it. I Updated my answer. You can check

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngx-extended-pdf-viewer` instead which has the feature of `Full-screen` mode.

So install the library like this:

```
npm i ngx-extended-pdf-viewer --save
```

Now open the file `angular.json` and configure Angular to copy the assets folder of the library into the assets folder of your application, however, if you want to use the developer preview of `pdf.js 2.10`, also import the `bleeding edge` files:

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
    "output": "/assets/"
  },
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/bleeding-edge/",
    "output": "/bleeding-edge/"
  }
],
"scripts": []
```

You will also need to add the following lines to your component:

```
import { pdfDefaultOptions } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';

//...

pdfDefaultOptions.assetsFolder = 'bleeding-edge';
```

Now you can display the PDF (in case of Blob) file like this:

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="'assets/example.pdf'" useBrowserLocale="true" height="80vh"></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

or you can display the PDF (in case of Base64 encoded string) file like this:

```
 <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [base64Src]="'assets/example.pdf'" useBrowserLocale="true" height="80vh"></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did
imports are

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
```

and the code in component.ts

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any){}
  elem:any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elem = document.documentElement;
  }


  openFullscreen() {
    this.elem.requestFullscreen();
  }

  /* Close fullscreen */
  closeFullscreen() {
    this.document.exitFullscreen();
  }
```

and in html

```
  <button (click)="openFullscreen()">Go full screen</button>
<button (click)="closeFullscreen()">Exit full screen</button>
```

and it worked like a charm

Comment: source : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-go-full-screen-f11-key?file=src/app/app.module.ts